# Python: How do I pass a big string as a single argument?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass an entire string as an argument to a python script.  The problem I am having is that the Python assumes that I only want the first word of the string.

In the example below, the `-l` arg stands for log and I want it to capture the entire string.

example:

```
python myscript.py -l "Big String I want to as single argument"
```

code below:

```
try:
  opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hcrn:l:wo:a:emi', ["reset="])
  #-l is one of many arguments I'm looking for
except getopt.error, err:
  print str(err)
  sys.exit(2)

for o, a in getopts:
    if o in ("-l", "--log"):  #log
    logIt(a)  # Problem here a='Big'
```

How do I get the entire string for the first argument, not just the first word?  Example please.

Comment: Works for me. What OS or shell are you using?

Comment: in the loop, what getopts is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly given you correct it.
The problem is probably in your `logIt` function.
If I correct this (it actually **does not work** in its posted form):

```
for o, a in getopts:
    if o in ("-l", "--log"):  #log
    logIt(a)  # Problem here a='Big'
```

with this (and using `print`):

```
for o, a in opts:
    if o in ("-l", "--log"):  #log
        print a  # No Problem here a=["Big String I want to as single argument"]
```

it prints what is should print:

```
C:\Python26>python myscript.py -l "Big String I want to as single argument"
Big String I want to as single argument
```

So probably your problem is not with `getopt` but with your `logIt` function.

Comment: Wierd...  It doesn't work the same way on my system.  If I add a print statement before logIt, only "Big" is printed.

Comment: @codingJoe I added my output in the cmd shell. This is python 2.6 in windows XP and the initial answer was tested on win 7. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.6 on win 7.  All driven from cygwin command line.    Looking back, this error is relatively new and this same code used to work fine.  But you're right... it should work.  My temporary solution was to pop an easygui window and capture the "Big Long String" that way.

Answer (score 2):

First: getopt is pretty outdated and deprecated.

Please use the optparse module of Python or the even newer argparse module (there is a backport of argparse for Python 2.X on PyPI).

The first example clearly covers your usecase solved using optparse:

http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                  help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: My appologies, I'm not seeing it.  I clearly see how OptionParser can accept single word arguments. But, I can't find any examples where OptionParser accepts "a string in quotes" as a single argument.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Is that supposed to be opts

```
try:
  opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hcrn:l:wo:a:emi', ["reset="])
  #-l is one of many arguments I'm looking for
except getopt.error, err:
  print str(err)
  sys.exit(2)

for o, a in opts:
    if o in ("-l", "--log"):  #log
    logIt(a)
```